# Error passing Unicode string through JSONObject

Tags: java, unicode, json

I have to pass unicode string to a JSONObject.

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject("{\"One\":\"\\ud83c\\udf45\\ud83c\\udf46\"}");
json.put("Two", "\ud83c\udf45\ud83c\udf46");
System.out.println(json.toString());
```

but I have this:

```
{"One":"","Two":""}
```

I want this:

```
{"One":"\ud83c\udf45\ud83c\udf46","Two":"\ud83c\udf45\ud83c\udf46"}
```

Comment: Have you tried escaping your string?
`json.put("Two", "\\ud83c\\udf45\\ud83c\\udf46");`

Comment: I have this: {"One":"","Two":"\\ud83c\\udf45\\ud83c\\udf46"}

Comment: @LutzHorn: read the [JSON spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf), Section 9...

Comment: @LutzHorn: *If the code point is in the Basic Multilingual Plane (U+0000 through U+FFFF), then it may be represented as a six-character sequence: a reverse solidus, followed by the lowercase letter u, followed by four hexadecimal digits that encode the code point... To escape a code point that is not in the Basic Multilingual Plane, the character is represented as a twelve-character sequence, **encoding the UTF-16 surrogate pair**. So for example, a string containing only the G clef character (U+1D11E) may be represented as "\uD834\uDD1E".*

Comment: @LutzHorn: and my comments were to tell you that they ARE valid Unicode characters. They are encoded as UTF-16 surrogate pairs, per JSON spec section 9 that I quoted. `\ud83c\udf45` represents `U+1F345 TOMATO` and `\ud83c\udf46` represents `U+1F346 AUBERGINE`.

Answer (score 3):

The system is working as designed. You are just not taking into account that JSON does not *require* most Unicode characters to be formatted in `\uXXXX` format.  Certain escape characters *must* be in `\X` format, and control characters <= 0x1F *must* be in `\uXXXX` format, but any other character **may** be in `\uXXXX` format but is not *required* to be.  The characters you have shown do not fall into those ranges, which is why `toString()` is not encoding them in `\uXXXX` format.

When you call `new JSONObject(String)`, it decodes the input string into actual Unicode strings, as if you had done this instead:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("One", "\ud83c\udf45\ud83c\udf46");
```

Which is perfectly fine.  You *want* the `JSONObject` to hold un-escaped Unicode data internally.

Where you are getting tripped up is the fact that `JSONObject.toString()` is not formatting your particular Unicode characters in `\uXXXX` format.  That is perfectly valid JSON, but is not how you are wanting them to be formatted (why do you want them formatted this way?).

A look at the source for Java's `JSONStringer` class (which implements `JSONObject.toString()`) reveals that it only formats non-reserved control characters <= 0x1F in `\uXXXX` format, other non-reserved characters are formatted as-is. This conforms to the JSON specification.

To do what you are asking for, you will have to manually format Unicode characters as needed after calling `JSONObject.toString()` to format reserved and ASCII characters normally, eg:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject("{\"One\":\"\\ud83c\\udf45\\ud83c\\udf46\"}");
// decodes as if json.put("One", "\ud83c\udf45\ud83c\udf46")
// or json.put("One", "") were called directly ...

json.put("Two", "\ud83c\udf45\ud83c\udf46");
// same as calling json.put("Two", "") ...

String s = json.toString();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i)
{
    char ch = s.charAt(i);
    if (ch >= 0x7F)
        sb.append(String.format("\\u%04x", (int) ch));
    else
        sb.append(ch);
}

System.out.println(sb.toString());
// outputs '{"One":"\ud83c\udf45\ud83c\udf46","Two":"\ud83c\udf45\ud83c\udf46"}' as expected ...
```

Answer (score -1):

One way of doing this is:

```
json.put("Two", "\\u" + "d83c" + "\\u" + "df45" + ...);
```

This will print the string literal `\ud83c\udf45` when you try to print the JSON.

Comment: That is no different than using `json.put("Two", "\\ud83c\\udf45...");`, as the concatenation occurs before `put()` is called.

Comment: This is telling the library to insert the literal value `\ud83c` where the ``\`` must be escaped in JSON.